# Java excel sheet uploading to mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, excel

In my application I need to upload a excel sheet and get those data to my calculations. So I am using this java code to do upload function

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/smartmenu","root","");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C://Users/Dhananjana/Desktop/tes/test.xls");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            row = (Row)sheet.getRow(i);
            int id = (int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
            String name = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            String address = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+address+"')";
            pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.execute();
            System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
        }
        con.commit();
        pstm.close();
```

While I am trying this code but I got the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
>       at employee.payroll.system.ImportData.main(ImportData.java:33)
>   ::: line 33  :::: row = (Row)sheet.getRow(i);

How can I solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Row row;` to `HSSFRow row;`. If needed, add `import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: int id = (int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                String name = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                String address = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

Comment: sorry I got these lines as error lines now so what to do now